mod p cohomology of a p-group P vs. the one of P/Z(G)
Let $P$ be a p-group. Denote by $Z(G)$ its center and $H^*(P,\mathbb{F}_p)$ its mod $p$ cohomology ring.
My general (vague) question is what can be said about the mod $p$ cohomology of the central extension
$$1 \rightarrow Z(P) \rightarrow P \rightarrow P/Z(P)$$
and in particular when $Z(P)$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group?
More specifically, I am wondering the following:
Let $\varphi$ be an automorphism of $P$ which acts as identity on $H(Z(G),\mathbb{F}_p)$  and $H^* (P,\mathbb{F}_p)$. Does $\varphi$ then also acts as identity on $H^*(P/Z(P), \mathbb{F}_p)$?

In case when P is extraspecial, then the answer is yes, because corestriction is just a quotient map from the cohomology of elementary (which is a polynomial algebra generated by Bocksteins of H^1 = P/Z(P)*) to the cohomology of P. In general I suspect it's not true.

I imagine that you are aware of the Lyndon-Hochschild-Serre spectral sequence, with $E_2^{i,j}= H^i(P/Z)\otimes H^j(Z)$ and converging to a filtration of $H^*(P)$?  As Denis T says, the answer to your question is probably `no' in general, but not many computations have been done.
